# Checking for Facebook Login on Website from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I want to check from a Chrome extension if I logged in to my website on Google Chrome using the Facebook SDK from javascript and also get the user access token. Right now I am trying to use the following login request on the website:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?
client_id={app-id}
&redirect_uri={"https://www.example.com/login"}
```

However, although I am able to call the "https://www.example.com/login" from the chrome extension, I am unable to get the access token for the login. From the chrome extension, how do I determine if somebody has logged into the web app at www.example.com and subsequently get their access token?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create check login method e.g. `https://www.example.com/checkLogin` and call it instead of calling the `https://www.example.com/login` url. The `https://www.example.com/checkLogin` method should return all the required information that you need along with the access token. You can subsequently store the token and other information in the localStorage that way will not have to call the `checkLogin` method everytime, but this must be synced with your website. So if the user logout from website he must also be logged out from the chrome extension.